# Customised Combining Diacritical Symbols Keyboard for Android

Tags: java, android, android-layout, diacritics, custom-keyboard

I want to develop a custom keyboard for android phones using android studio having keys for typing combining diacritical marks like above ring symbol (U+030A).

I am able to type Å using Unicode but unable to type ◌̊. I have no idea how to implement this in Java using android studio.